# Use a calculated column value to look up a specific value from the same source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server called `ShippingDocSummary` which contains all historical records for shipping documents. For a given document number, there can be any number of historical records/transactions. What I am trying to do is create a view that summarizes that table and calculates various column values. My issue comes when trying to get a specific value from the source table based on a calculated column value from the same source table.

Here is a simplified example of what the source table looks like:

```
DocNum    DocHistID    StatusCode   StatusQty    StatusDate
12345     10000001     AS1          2            2/16/2020
12345     10000002     D6T          2            4/20/2020
12345     10000003     COR          2            4/20/2020
12345     10000004     AS1          2             5/5/2020
```

My code to create my summary so far is as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  DocNum,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'AS_' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) AS AS_QTY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'D6T' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) AS D6T_QTY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'COR' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) AS COR_QTY,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'AS_' THEN DocHistID ELSE null END) AS LastAS_DHID
FROM ShippingDocSummary
GROUP BY DocNum
```

This gives me the following, which is correct:

```
DocNum    AS_QTY    D6T_QTY    COR_QTY    LastAS_DHID
12345     4         2          2          10000004
```

What I am trying to get next, as a column, is the `StatusDate` that correlates to the `LastAS_DHID` value that was calculated from the select (i.e. I need the next column to show '5/5/2020' since that date ties to the `DocHistID` '10000004').

In Power Bi, I'd use a `lookupvalue` function, but as I transfer my logic to the SQL server, I think I need to use a derived `CASE WHEN` type of query, but unsure of how to structure the syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the dates always in ascending order in parallel with the doc id?

Comment: The DocHistID's are all unique for the whole table so never any repeats. For a given doc number, the lowest DocHist ID will always be the first record for that doc and generally maps parallel with the StatusDates, but in the real table there can be dozens of transactions with different StatusCodes and DocHistID's that occur on the same date and the date does not have a timestamp, just the date. Also, I can't change the info coming to my system to add a timestamp to it, so the ID is the unique field I can play with.

Comment: I assumed that you wouldn't have asked it that were the case. Since the sample didn't make it clear I figured that asking would nevertheless be a good idea.

Comment: Never hurts to clarify, absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to create your on table and then do a left join. This being said, Try this:

```
SELECT A.DocNum,
A.AS_QTY,
A.D6T_QTY,
A.COR_QTY,
A.LastAS_DHID,
B.StatusDate

        FROM (
                SELECT DocNum,
                       SUM(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'AS_' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) AS AS_QTY,
                       SUM(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'D6T' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) AS D6T_QTY,
                       SUM(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'COR' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) AS COR_QTY,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'AS_' THEN DocHistID ELSE null END) AS LastAS_DHID
                
                       FROM ShippingDocSummary
                       GROUP BY DocNum) A
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_WITH_DOCHIST_10000004 B
        ON A.LastAS_DHID = B.DocHistID
```

Comment: I will give this a try and see what the results are, thank you

Comment: This took care of it and gave me the expected result, thank you! If I have additional columns that would get pulled in this same fashion, would I need multiple nested statements with multiple joins?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DocNum,
  SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCode LIKE 'AS_' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNum) AS AS_QTY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCode LIKE 'D6T' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNum) AS D6T_QTY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCode LIKE 'COR' THEN StatusQty ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNum) AS COR_QTY,
  FIRST_VALUE(StatusDate) OVER (PARTITION BY DocNum ORDER BY CASE WHEN StatusCode LIKE 'AS_' THEN DocHistID ELSE null END DESC) AS LastAS_DHID
FROM ShippingDocSummary
```

I've converted your aggregate functions to windowed versions with partitioning on the original grouping column. The `select distinct` is then necessary to actually collapse the rows to a single aggregated row. If `first_value()` isn't available on your platform there are other alternatives.

Here's one that worked for me as a scalar subquery:

```
(
SELECT StatusDate FROM ShippingDocSummary sds2
WHERE sds2.DocHistId =
  MAX(
    CASE WHEN ShippingDocSummary.StatusCode LIKE 'AS_'
         THEN ShippingDocSummary.DocHistID ELSE null END
  )
) AS LastAS_DHID
```